# A window opens and closes after 30-40 seconds (JS)

Tags: javascript

I have a piece of code, and I want to run it on a website:

```
var allURL = [
    episodeLinks.join(""),

];

function showUrl(index) {
    index = index || 0;
 
    if (allURL.length === 0 || index < 0 || index >= allURL.length) {
        return;
    }

   
    var popup = window.open(allURL[index]);


    setTimeout(function() {
        popup.close();
        showUrl(index + 1);
    }, 40000);
}

showUrl();
```

In the first part it simply looks for links and I want to take these links automatically

This is the second part:

```
const seasons = document.querySelectorAll("#season li");
const episodes = document.querySelectorAll("#episode li");



let $prak = '1',
  episodeLinks = [];

seasons.forEach(seasonLi => {
  const season = seasonLi.textContent.trim();
  episodes
    .forEach(episodeLi => {
      const episode = episodeLi.textContent.trim();
      const url = `https://www.test.com/watch/${$prak}/season/${season}/episode/${episode}`
      episodeLinks.push(`${url}`)
    });
});
```

In practice, he writes to me in the URL:
https://www.test.com/watch/1/season/1/episode/1https://www.test.com/watch/1/season/1/episode/2........

And I need it to run for me once on each link between 30-40 seconds and close and reopen

Comment: A window, once opened, is out of your control. Also, most browsers completely block that kind of popup nowadays, unless it's triggered _by the user_ clicking on something.

Comment: If the URL is to a different domain, you can not control it. Same Origin Policy